# Python - inserting values from inner loop with those from outer loop within a table

Tags: python, regex, nested-loops, arcpy

I have a script that's parsing through text within each record of a table/field, and inserting those values into field/records of another table.  Here's an example of the text being parsed (from "Field1"):

*Name Multiple Words* (0/24.56) Name Multiple Words2* (96/24.56) Name Multiple Words3* (0) Name Multiple Words4* (96/12.58) Name Multiple Words5* (96/78.12) Name Multiple Words6* (0/98.32) Name Multiple Words7* (96/0) Name Multiple Words8* (0) Name Multiple Words9**

Here's the script:

```
import re, arcpy, sys

# Local variables:
Table2 = "D:\Source_Data_Convert.gdb\Table2"
RAW_Data = "D:\Source_Data_Convert.gdb\RAW_Data_Table2"

#Create Cursors and Insert Rows
insertcursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(Table2, ["Other_Stuff", "That_Stuff", "Some_More", "From", "To", "Num_One", "Num_Two", "Nums"])
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(RAW_Data, ["Field1", "Other_Stuff", "That_Stuff", "Some_More"]) as searchcursor:
########  Start the SearchCursor Loop ###################   
        for row in searchcursor:
            try:
                Other_Stuff = row[1]
                That_Stuff = row[2]
                Some_More = row[3]
                listFrom = re.split(r'\*\s*\(.*?\)\s*', row[0])
                print listFrom

                Nums = re.findall(r'\(([^)]+)\)', row[0])
                for match in re.finditer(r'\(([^)]+)\)', row[0]):
                    parts = match.group(1).split('/')
                    print parts
                    First_Num = parts[0]
                try:
                    Second_Num = parts[1]
                except IndexError:
                    #Second_Num = None
                    Second_Num = 0
                    print "First_Num, Second_Num: ", First_Num, Second_Num

                print "Parsing Successful"

############  Start the Insertcursor Loop ############          
                for n,Value in enumerate(match): #enumerate is essentially doing a count
                    insertcursor.insertRow((Other_Stuff, That_Stuff, Some_More, listFrom[n], listFrom[n+1], First_Num[n], Second_Num[n+1], Nums[n]))
                    print "Data Inserted"
            except:
                pass
            else:
                break

del insertcursor
del searchcursor
del row
```

I can get the values to print correctly, but I can't seem to get the (2) values from the nested loop to insert with each (1) value from the outer loop.  Hopefully my question makes sense.  Basically I'm trying to populate (3) fields.  One field gets the values from the outer loop, the other two fields get the values (resulting from the split) from the inner loop.  Any help would much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `First_Num` and `Second_Num` are not lists, but strings, so `Second_Num[n+1]` is certainly not what you want.

Comment: A couple of things. I can tell you are coming from a different language you do not need to do explicit `del` in Python it has automatic garbage collection, I would avoid the overarching `try: except: else:` block you have because you will miss exceptions and it makes it a royal pain to debug.

Comment: @Jan, when I remove the [n] and [n+1] the First_Num and Second_Num fields are populated with the last set of values from the inner loop.  I need those values insert into the same row of the table as the Nums value they came from (i.e. Nums = 96/12.56, Fist_Num = 96, Second_Num = 12.56)

Answer (score 0):

Compile everything that you want to print or handle into a list of dictionary items. This way you can group up data that you want to print more easily.

So you can have something like this:

```
field_dict['firstField'] = someValue
field_dict['secondField'] = someList
field_dict['thirdField'] = someValue
dict_list.append(field_dict)
```

Then at the end you can just loop through the list and print however you want without being bound by your nested loops.